# Material UI Texboxes Dynamically created form Array Disply in multi columns ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I get a list of cars from a API, i have the following code to create the list of labels and textboxed to edit the car code.

```
  {!carQuery.loading &&
            carDefinitions?.map((car: ICarType, idx: number) =>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id={car.name}
                    label={car.name}
                    defaultValue={car.code}
                    name={car.name}
                    key={idx}
                    onChange={e => {
                        const code = carDefinitions.filter(x => x.name === e.target.name);
                        shortCut[0].code = e.target.value;
                    }}
                />)
```

The issue I have is there can be over 50 cars, so the form is really long, any ideas how i could make this easier than one long form, like columns or pagination. Im not sure what is best

```
interface ICarType
{
    name: string;
    code: string;
    isDiesel: boolean;
}
```

Comment: you can use pagination that comes from Material-UI tables, and o each Table row you display one checkbox(or more if thats the case)

Comment: thanks! how would you do that dynamically in the loop i have above?

Comment: Can you supply one `car` object? I will create a sandbox to show you how implement in in a table with pagination

Comment: sure i added it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Pagination** from Material-UI Lab, *(read more [Here](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/))*

I created a `PaginationComponent` iterates through an array of objects and paginate them. The component uses two props in order to work

1. `items` - the array of objects you want to iterate
2. `itemsPerPage` - the number of items displayed on a page

***Note***

In this pagination example I used your `<TextField/>` component with the props you provided in your question.

Also I've modified the handler for `onChange` on the `<TextField/>` component in order to work in the sandbox.

Please adapt the code to your needs, this is just a MVP to demonstrate how pagination works

***Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-keller-1v192)***

```js
const PaginationComponent = ({ items, itemsPerPage }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const handleChangePage = useCallback((e, v) => setPage(v - 1), []);

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="stretch">
      <Grid item>
        {items
          .slice(page * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage)
          .map((car, idx) => (
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              id={car.name}
              label={car.name}
              defaultValue={car.code}
              name={car.name}
              key={idx}
              onChange={e => console.log(e.target)}
            />
          ))}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Pagination
          count={Math.ceil(items.length / itemsPerPage)}
          onChange={handleChangePage}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Comment: this is great! thanks, is there a way to just shoow them in a grid with three or four ietsm per row? Dynamically with that loop i had?

Comment: It would be nice to understand both options

Comment: @MicroMan I've updated the sandbox with another prop `itemsPerRow` take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-keller-1v192